# How to install chart of accounts automatically without inputting data on the Chart of Account initialization wizard?

Tags: odoo

I have been trying to automate module installation from a http controller. Installation of module has been succeeded and since accounting module has some wizards to be processed, they are not executed and they are in open state in `ir.actions.todo` table. So I took an example from `addons/account/account_pre_install.yml` and modified it accordingly. The problem is, the `write` method on `ir.actions.todo` model is not working and `create` and `execute_simple` methods on `account.installer` model are not working.

Here is the whole code for that particular controller.

```
@http.route('/saas_worker/module', type="json", auth="none")
def check_module(self, fields):
    params = dict(map(operator.itemgetter('name', 'value'), fields))
    super_admin_password = config.get("admin_passwd")
    response_data = {}

    create_attrs = (
        super_admin_password,
        params["db_name"],
        False,
        params["db_lang"],
        params["create_admin_password"]
    )

db_created = request.session.proxy("db").create_database(*create_attrs)

if db_created:
    db = openerp.sql_db.db_connect(params["db_name"])
    with closing(db.cursor()) as cr:
        registry = openerp.modules.registry.RegistryManager.new(cr.dbname, update_module=True)
        ir_module = registry['ir.module.module']
        ir_model_data = registry['ir.model.data']
        wizards = registry['ir.actions.todo']
        res_partner = registry['res.partner']
        account_installer = registry['account.installer']
        selected_modules = params["modules"].split(",")
        module_ids = ir_module.search(cr,SUPERUSER_ID,[('name','in',selected_modules)])

        #Install modules automatically
        ir_module.button_immediate_install(cr,SUPERUSER_ID,module_ids,None)
        wizard = wizards.browse(cr,SUPERUSER_ID,self.ref(cr, SUPERUSER_ID,   ir_model_data,'account.account_configuration_installer_todo'))

        if wizard.state=='open':
            mod='l10n_us'
            ids = ir_module.search(cr, SUPERUSER_ID, [ ('name','=',mod) ], context=None)

            if ids:
                 wizards.write(cr, SUPERUSER_ID, self.ref(cr, SUPERUSER_ID, ir_model_data,'account.account_configuration_installer_todo'), {'state': 'done'})

                 wizard_id = account_installer.create(cr, SUPERUSER_ID, {'charts': mod})
                 account_installer.execute_simple(cr, SUPERUSER_ID, [wizard_id])

                 ir_module.state_update(cr, SUPERUSER_ID, ids,'to install', ['uninstalled'], context=None)
                 response_data["status"] = "ok"
                 response = json.dumps(response_data)

                 return response

def ref(self, cr, uid, registry_obj, external_id):
    return registry_obj.xmlid_to_res_id(cr, uid, external_id, raise_if_not_found=True)
```